# compare values in two xml files

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I have the xml file sentence.xml with the following format:

```
<doc>
   <sentence id="sent_1" span="word_1..word_8"/>
   <sentence id="sent_2" span="word_9..word_15"/>
   <sentence id="sent_3" span="word_16..word_22"/>
   <sentence id="sent_4" span="word_23..word_30"/>
</doc>
```

This xml file shows that for example, my first sentence with the @id="sent_1" is from word_1 to word_8. The second sentence (@id="sent_2") is from word_9 to word_15, etc.

My second xml file verb.xml has the following format.

```
<verb id="v1" span="word_3"/>
<verb id="v2" span="word_7"/>
<verb id="v3" span="word_14"/>
<verb id="v4" span="word_27"/>
```

Which means: the first verb (@id="v1") is "word_3"; the second verb (@id="v2") is "word_7", etc.

If we compare both xml files, we see that e.g. the first verb (v1) in verb.xml which is word_3 belongs to the first sentence (sent_1); the third verb (v3) which is word_14 belongs to the second sentence (sent_2), etc.

What I want to have as the output is to compare the value of the span attribute of both files and see to which sentence, the verb belongs to. So for example, word_3 in somewhere in the span word_1..word_8 (which is our first sentence). The output should look like this:

```
<verb id="v1" span="word_3" ref="sent_1"/>
<verb id="v2" span="word_7" ref="sent_1"/>
<verb id="v3" span="word_14" ref="sent_2"/>
<verb id="v4" span="word_27" ref="sent_4"/>
```

I hope my explanation is clear.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the numbers from the range descriptions like `word_1..word_8` and then reference them from the number extracted from a span value like `word_3`. In XSLT 3 you can easily do that with a key set up for the `sentence` element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="sentence-doc">
    <doc>
       <sentence id="sent_1" span="word_1..word_8"/>
       <sentence id="sent_2" span="word_9..word_15"/>
       <sentence id="sent_3" span="word_16..word_22"/>
       <sentence id="sent_4" span="word_23..word_30"/>
    </doc>
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:key name="ref" match="sentence" 
    use="let $numbers := analyze-string(@span, 'word_([0-9]+)\.\.word_([0-9]+)')//*:group/xs:integer(.)
         return $numbers[1] to $numbers[2]"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="verb">
      <verb id="{@id}" span="{@span}" ref="{key('ref', @span => replace('[^0-9]+', '')=>xs:integer(), $sentence-doc)/@id}"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBt2 for an online demo. Of course for your case with two input documents you could use `<xsl:param name="sentence-doc" select="doc('sentence.xml')"/>` instead of including the data inline, as I have done in the online sample.